# add text on heatmap using locator()

Tags: r, text, orientation, heatmap, label

I'm creating an heatmap through `heatmap.2()`. I'd like to put the xaxis labels rotate of 45 degree. Following the instructions in other posts, I tried to do this building an heatmap without x labels and then using `text()` to add them...
This is what I tried:

```
#fake matrix
cheese.matrix <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
#build color palette
my.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red"), space="rgb")
#build a first heatmap
hm_cheese <- heatmap.2(cheese.matrix,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=my.palette,
                       density.info=c("none"),margins(3,5),cexRow=0.8,
                       cexCol=0.8,key=TRUE,keysize=1,trace="none",
                       lhei=c(2,8), breaks=100)
#find the coordinates on the plot where I want to pu the first and the last label
pos2 <- locator()
pos2
$x
[1] 0.08129779 0.90164993

$y
[1] -0.06905376 -0.06372554

pos2 <- structure(list(x=c(0.08129779, 0.90164993), y=c(-0.06905376, -0.06372554)), .Names=c("x","y"))
#create a vector with the labels I want to add
labs <- c("NWC1.PR", "CURD1.PR", "NWC2.PR","CURD2.PR","NWC3.PR","CURD3.PR",  "NWC4.PR", "CURD4.PR", "NWC5.PR", "CURD5.PR")
#build another heatmap
hm_cheese <- heatmap.2(cheese.matrix,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=my.palette,
                      density.info=c("none"),margins(3,5),key=TRUE,
                      keysize=1,trace="none", lhei=c(2,8), breaks=100, 
                      labCol="", add.expr=text(x=seq(pos2$x[1], pos2$x[2], len=10),
                      y=rep(pos2$y[1],10), srt=45, xpd=TRUE, adj=0, labels=labs))
```

This put the labels on the heatmap, but all the names were overlying...
I also tried this:

```
hm_cheese2 <-heatmap.2(cheese.matrix,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=my.palette,
                       density.info=c("none"),margins(3,5),key=TRUE,keysize=1,
                       trace="none", lhei=c(2,8), breaks=100, labCol="", 
                       add.expr=text(x=seq_along(labs), y=-0.06372554, srt=45,
                       xpd=TRUE, adj=0, labels=labs))
```

The result was better, since the labels were along the axis, but still really close among them and overlying the plot...

Is there anything wrong in the way I used `locator()` to find the coordinates?
Can anyone help me to improve my code?

Comment: I'm intrigued by the idea of a cheese.matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with argument `pos` in your call to `text`. By using `pos=1` for example:

```
hm_cheese2 <-heatmap.2(cheese.matrix,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=my.palette,
                       density.info=c("none"),margins(3,5),key=TRUE,keysize=1,
                       trace="none", lhei=c(2,8), breaks=100, labCol="", 
                       add.expr=text(x=seq_along(labs), y=-0.06372554, srt=45,
                       xpd=TRUE, adj=0, labels=labs, pos=1))
```

[image]

See `?text` for more on `pos`.

If the labels fall outside the plot, you can try using `xpd=NA` to clip them to the device region instead of the plot or the figure regions.

```
hm_cheese2 <-heatmap.2(cheese.matrix,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=my.palette,
                       density.info=c("none"),margins(3,5),key=TRUE,keysize=1,
                       trace="none", lhei=c(2,8), breaks=100, labCol="", 
                       add.expr=text(x=seq_along(labs), y=-0.06372554, srt=45,
                       xpd=NA, adj=0, labels=labs, pos=1))
```

Comment: Hi plannapus! thanks for your help! using pos really improved the situation, but since I have more labels than the 10 used for the exemple (my real matrix has 50 columns), the last part of the first label is cut! So it didn't enter in the plot area... I also tried using margins(0,0) or to reduce the font size, but a part of the first labe is always outside... Is there a way to have a bigger plot area?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis see edit: the simplest thing would be to clip the labels to the device and not to the figure using `xpd=NA`. However my advice if you have a lot of labels honestly would be not to plot them with a 45° but vertically to improve legibility.